# Interpretation of clogit coefficients (Survival package in R)

Tags: r, interpretation, clogit, odds, conjoint-analysis

Still very very new to R! I've run a conjoint (choice) experiment that uses the function clogit. Output as follows: (this model has been obtained through stepwise methods)

```
clogout3a <- clogit(RES ~ ASC + Tasmania + Import + Price + strata(STR),data = dataset1)
> clogout3a
Call:
clogit(RES ~ ASC + Tasmania + Import + Price + strata(STR), data = dataset1)


           coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z       p
ASC       2.096     8.135   0.1270  16.51 0.0e+00
Tasmania  0.457     1.580   0.1053   4.34 1.4e-05
Import   -0.172     0.842   0.1330  -1.29 2.0e-01
Price    -0.526     0.591   0.0505 -10.41 0.0e+00

Likelihood ratio test=512  on 4 df, p=0  n= 3402, number of events= 1134 
> gofm(clogout3a)

Rho-squared = 0.2053607 
Adjusted rho-squared = 0.20215 
Akaike information criterion (AIC) = 1987.965 
Bayesian information criterion (BIC) = 2008.099 
Number of coefficients = 4 
Log likelihood at start = -1245.826 
Log likelihood at convergence = -989.9825
```

As an example, would I be corrected in saying that the odds of choosing a Tasmania product would be 1.58 times higher than the base (in this case a generic Australian product)? Or is it correct to say that a person is 1.58 times more likely to choose a product if it is a Tasmania product? (Or are this statements saying exactly the same thing??).

I've tried to find examples but have had no luck. Thanks in advance!